# How to generate laravel request in namespace path for laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm familiar with the laravel artisan command

> make:request

however I can't seem to get it to place it in a directory. For example I have a directory structure

> app/Http/Requests/User

and I'd like to place a request in that folder namespaced appropriately but

```
php artisan make:request User\CreateUserRequest
```

doesn't work.

Comment: `User\CreateUserRequest` works for me. It will create a file, `CreateUserRequest.php` in `app/Http/Requests/User` namespaced (in file) `App\Http\Requests\User`. There is no way to set root directory with the command. If you want to have it in a directory outside `app/Http/Requests` you can move it manually.

Comment: did you try to run php artisan make:request User\\CreateUserRequest ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`artisan make:request User\\CreateUserRequest`

thanks to [@DarrylCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440220/how-to-generate-laravel-request-in-namespace-path-for-laravel-5#comment41541998_26440220) for answering in the comments

Comment: And what's the difference here from original question? I see here the same code as in question and in my answer.

Comment: hmm... double backslash was the difference but must have gotten stripped

Answer (score 5):

Switch the slash (**/**) direction to forward:

```
php artisan make:request User/CreateUserRequest
```

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan make:request Auth\\CreateUserRequest`

that will make request file in `Requests\Auth` folder

OR

`php artisan make:request Auth/CreateUserRequest`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have in your `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

You should have this part `psr-4` (it's set by default here) .

Now you should rather don't use `app/Requests/User` but `app/Http/Requests/User` because `Requests` should be placed in `Http` directory.

Now when you run `php artisan make:request User\CreateUserRequest` you should get response from artisan:

> \Request created successfully.

and in your `app/Http/Requests/User` directory you should have file `CreateUserRequest.php`

I've checked it a moment ago and it works fine. Of course it's possible that in the version you have installed you have a bug or you changed some other app settings so you could try update it to the newest version (I've tested it on version I've downloaded a couple days ago).

Comment: hmm.. set up is so far pretty vanilla with the psr-4. make:request User\request puts it in the Requests root folder. However User/Request will use the correct folder but names the class User/Request instead of adding it to the namespace

Comment: @matthewdaniel You need to use '\` in `make:request`. As I said it works without a problem, so if you did exactly what I wrote and it doesn't work with you, you should try update or create fresh project and try it there.

Answer (score 0):

The following example demonstrates how to call the make:request command

```
php artisan make:request SignInRequest
```

**app/Http/Requests/StoreDrinksPostRequest.php** goto this file and edit **function rules()**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class StoreDrinksPostRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```